# Angular: Why does field $invalid is true in other view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added some condition to show my revision field. Basically it will accept a number and a required field , so i added some validation check. I have excluded this field from 'edit' view. and for that i specified condition as well.

```
 ng-show="editMode=='addNew' || editMode=='addDate'"
```

even though in edit view my field is not showing up.. but somewhere $invalid is becoming true for all view

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-show="editMode=='addNew' || editMode=='addDate'">
     <label for="editmyRevision" ng-class="{'col-sm-3':editMode=='addNew'}"  class="col-md-2 control-label">Revision</label>
    <div ng-class="{'col-sm-9':editMode=='addNew'}" class="col-md-10">
     <input class="form-control" ng-model="editmyRevision"name="revision" ng-required="editMode=='addNew' || editMode =='addDate'" ng-maxlength="5" ng-Pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"></input>
       <span class="has-error help-block" data-ng-show="prodEdit.revision.$invalid">Acceptable formats: 100~99999</span>

   </div>
    </div>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-show` will not remove the input from the form. It will just set `display:none` style to it, so it will still make the form invalid.

Try using `ng-if` instead.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-if="editMode=='addNew' || editMode=='addDate'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Many `error syntax` in your code. `$invalid` apply for `form` not `input`.

Change:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="editmyRevision"name="revision" ng-required="editMode=='addNew' || editMode =='addDate'" ng-maxlength="5" ng-Pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"></input>
<span class="has-error help-block" data-ng-show="prodEdit.revision.$invalid">Acceptable formats: 100~99999</span>
```

To:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="editmyRevision" name="revision" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{3,5}$/"/>
<span class="has-error help-block" data-ng-show="prodEdit.revision.$error">
   Acceptable formats: 100~99999
</span>
```